# Moveend triggering in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add markers via Json once a visitor moves the map. For some reason the moveend is not caught and / or the function onClickCallback is not triggered. Where am I going wrong here.

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
  var bounds = this.getBounds();
  onClickCallback(map);

 });


function onClickCallback(map) {

var bounds = map.getBounds();


  // clearOverlays();



    $.getJSON( 'http://skiweather.eu/gmap4/markers/index.php', {
        swLat: bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), swLon: bounds.getSouthWest().lng(), 
        neLat: bounds.getNorthEast().lat(), neLon: bounds.getNorthEast().lng()}, function(data) { 
        $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {


        // Define Marker properties
        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker.smallimg,
        // This marker is 129 pixels wide by 42 pixels tall.
            new google.maps.Size(42, 42),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 18,42.
            new google.maps.Point(18, 42)
        );


            $('#map').gmap('addMarker', { 'id' : marker.id,
                'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude),
                'icon' : image,             
                'bounds': true 
            }).click(function() {
                $('#map').gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': '<h2>' + marker.loc + '</h2><img src="' + marker.smallimg + '" class="my-map-marker" />'
                 }, this);
            });
        });
    });




}   


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `moveend` event is no longer available in google.maps V3, use `dragend` instead.

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function() {
    var bounds = this.getBounds();
    onClickCallback(map);

});
```

Comment: The strange thing it triggers the ajax call when the bounds are changed when loading the original request, but not after that. Also the markers are not added http://skiweather.eu/gmap4/?res_id=6

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question.

I found the answer in [google reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1);

Event: **idle**

Arguments:  None

This event is fired when the map becomes idle after **panning** or **zooming**.

Answer (score 0):

From one post at [groops google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/4epVU9NJ0TQ).

google.maps *V3 is missing some important V2 events on the whole map:*

```
mousemove 
mouseover 
mouseout 
movebegin 
moveend
```

It seems `bounds_changed` could help. See also comment from user *sabotero* about `dragend`.

Comment: `bounds_changed` will be fired several times while "moving" the map. In this case is better to use the `dragend` event instead which is fired only once when the map stop "moving"